# Adjusting the labelling of pie chart in R

Tags: r, visualization, pie-chart

I would like to create a pie chart of "no_car_21", in percentage. However, the label of the pie chart is clumped together. Therefore, I would like to know how can I extend the labeling so that the labels will not clump together.

My current pie chart is shown below:

[image]

My code:

```
pct <- round(100*fuel_trend$no_car_21/sum(fuel_trend$no_car_21)) 
              
pie(fuel_trend$no_car_21, 
    labels = paste(fuel_trend$fuel_type, sep = " ", pct, "%"), cex=0.8)
```

data frame:

```
fuel_type <- c("DIESEL", "DIESEL/ELECTRIC", "LPG", "PETROL", "PETROL/ELECTRIC")
no_car_21 <- c(3992, 199, 2224, 215199,30550)
fuel_trend <- data.frame(fuel_type, no_car_21)
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your correction. Will be more aware of this issue in the future.

Comment: Though not perfect, you can try to use ggplot2 (using https://r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html) and `ggrepel::geom_text_repel`. I don't know how to force the labels to occur outside of the circles, it's likely feasible but not immediately apparent to me.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer here is to change the plotting order so that the labels no longer clash. It will help a lot if you make your plotting window larger too.

```r
fuel_trend <- fuel_trend[c(4, 2, 5, 1, 3),]
pct <- round(100*fuel_trend$no_car_21/sum(fuel_trend$no_car_21)) 

pie(fuel_trend$no_car_21, 
    col = c( "#FBB4AE", "#B3CDE3", "#CCEBC5", "#DECBE4", "#FED9A6"),
    labels = paste(fuel_trend$fuel_type, sep = " ", pct, "%"), cex=0.8)
```

[image]